# Replicate a Null space in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to replicate this Null space in Matlab

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvyboGryeA8

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

With this vector as result

$$                         
  {X_3}   \begin{bmatrix}      
     1  \\                     
    -2  \\
     1  \\
     0  \\
     \end{bmatrix}                     
 $$

$$                         
  {X_4}   \begin{bmatrix}      
     2  \\                     
    -3  \\
     0  \\
     1  \\
     \end{bmatrix}                     
 $$

I try use this commands in matlab

```
A = [1 1 1 1; 1 2 3 4; 4 3 2 1]

Z = null(A)
```

But it doesn't show me that vectors. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Note that a 2-dimensional vector space has many possible bases

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What it means ? my command is correct?